# How to Center IMG within DIV in all browsers

Tags: css

I've read all Google top result tricks but I'm not able to center image within a div.

For example this popular trick: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/aa012207.htm or http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html
 does not work in IE 8.
I've tried another from Stackoverflow but it does not work in Opera.

So I think one trick is working in most browsers(IE8, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Maxthon, K-Melon, SeaMonkey):

```
<p style="text-align:center"><img  style="display: block;   margin-left: auto;   margin-right: auto;"   src="parliament.gif" width="200" height="71"></p>
```

**Any comments?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to center: a block element with explicit width, or an inline element:

http://jsfiddle.net/VNuFH/

Center a block image:

```
<div>
    <img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="...">
</div>
```

Center an inline image:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="...">
</div>
​
```

If you would want to center a shrink-wrapped div (for example image with caption), you could use the center float trick with one element:

http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

Comment: For now I want only an image within a div

Comment: The text is left aligned, that's expected. Is the image left-aligned too in the jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment but I was right - the first snippet is not aligning them in center in IE but it is in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can do this used **display table-cell** properties as like this

**Live demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/22cHK/

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
<img src="http://testing.gobanana.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/CrashTestDummy-2-8544b.jpg" >
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.center{
text-align:center;
    border:solid 10px red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
    width:700px;
    height:700px;
}
.center img{

}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/22cHK/

Comment: but the div is getting aligned in the left side while image is indeed in the center

Comment: You want to center the `div` containing the `img`? Would you clarify exactly what do you want to center?

Comment: @biziclop yes I want to center img within div so that image is shown in the horizontal center of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Do this it will work,

```
 <p style="text-align:center">
  <img  style="position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-35px 0 0 -100px;
  visibility:visible;
  src="parliament.gif">
 </p>
```

What happens here is the image top-left corner is positioned in the middle of p by using top:50%, left:50% but then using negative margin offsets the image to get to the middle. This trick works in all browsers.